# PostgreSQL : Use of ANY for multiple values

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, where-clause, any

I am trying to use the ANY function of PostgreSQL to search the value from array interger type column.

**My SQL:**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    company_employee_contacts
WHERE
    corporate_complaint_type_ids = ANY(ARRAY[1,3]::integer[])
```

But it is giving me below error:

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer[] = integer

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error while I am typecasting it?

Comment: because `corporate_complaint_type_ids` is not integer, but rather an array

Comment: corporate_complaint_type_ids is type of interger[]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

because `corporate_complaint_type_ids` is not integer, but rather array of integers... You can't:

```
select '{2,3,4}'::int[] = ANY(ARRAY[1,3]::integer[]);
ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer[] = integer
LINE 1: select '{2,3,4}'::int[] = ANY(ARRAY[1,3]::integer[]);
```

instead you can check if arrays [overlap](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-array.html):

```
postgres@pond93# select '{2,3,4}'::int[] && ARRAY[1,3]::integer[];
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

or you can check one array value against ANY(array):

```
postgres@pond93# select ('{2,3,4}'::int[])[1] = ANY(ARRAY[1,3]::integer[]);
 ?column?
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

Comment: "The operator for "overlap"  && " is working for me! Thanks